# Set Expansion Panel to be expanded, but also show animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material, angular9

I'm working in an Angular 9 project, using material.

I have a component with a `mat-accordian` with several `mat-expansion-panel`s inside. In the `constructor` of this component, I look at the `router.events` to view the `url`. Then, I set which expansion panel I want to expanded depending on what's in the url route.

The issue is when I do this, the panel is simply open when the page loads (which makes sense). However, I want the animation to play for the expansion panel I set to be open (after the page is loaded). Is there a way to do this?

I'll provide my code, if that helps show what I'm doing:

component.ts:

```
...
export class Component implements OnInit {
  routerSubscription: Subscription;
  expandPanel1 = false;
  expandPanel2 = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event["url"].includes("/panel-1")) {
          this.expandPanel1 = true;
        } else {
          this.expandPanel2 = true;
        }
      });
  }
...
setRoute(path: string) {
    this.router.navigate([`home/${path}`]);
  }
...
```

component.html:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expandPanel1" (opened)="setRoute('panel-1')">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Panel 1
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    panel text filler
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expandPanel2" (opened)="setRoute('panel-2')">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Panel 2
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
     panel text filler
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I'll appreciate any help and advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor will run first before anything else. So you could still get the route info in the constructor but, you should set one of the expandedPanel properties inside of the ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook instead of the constructor.

So something like:

```
   ...
export class Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  routerSubscription: Subscription;
  expandPanel1 = false;
  expandPanel2 = false;
  urlInfo: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(event => {
        urlInfo = event["url"];

      });
  }
...
setRoute(path: string) {
    this.router.navigate([`home/${path}`]);
  }

ngAfterViewInit(){
    if (this.urlInfo.includes("/panel-1")) {
         this.expandPanel1 = true;
    } 
    else {
        this.expandPanel2 = true;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This is great, I was thinking about using ngAfterViewInit, but knew I wouldn't be able to call the router events at that point. I didn't think about just setting a var in constructor and then using it in afterviewInit. TYSM